# operating on multiple columns in a slice

Tags: python, pandas

I want to operate on multiple columns in a slice of a DataFrame without having to create a new df.

For example, I want to add the values of a column with the values of its neighbor, but only under a certain condition. The below code works but is not very clean or readable. Is there a better way to do this in Pandas?

`Note`: I recognize there may be a better way to handle this specific condition (second column is not null) without slicing the dataframe at all, I'm looking generally for a pythonic way to operate on multiple columns in a slice.

```py
df.loc[~df["col2"].isnull(), "col1"] = (
    df.loc[~df["col2"].isnull(), "col1"]
    + "buffer"
    + df.loc[~df["col2"].isnull(), "col2"]
)
```

Comment: maybe just assign `df.loc[~df["col2"].isnull(), "col1"]` to a variable once and re-use that as a mask?

Comment: I would really like to find a way that doesn't involve creating a new DataFrame if at all possible. Thanks for your response though!

Comment: It wouldn't... you'd do something like: `m = df['col2'].notna()` and then use that

Comment: I see your point, it would be a Series not a DataFrame. Should have said I didn't want to create any extra variables.

Comment: you're still going to create something along the line to be able to do this... right now - just don't do it twice is all?

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
df["col1"] = df.loc[~df["col2"].isnull()].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! This will not work because it does not account for the possibility of the columns being strings or for there being more than 2 columns in the dataframe.

Comment: To restrict the sum over columns one can simply do: `df["col1"] = df.loc[~df["col2"].isnull(), ["col1", "col2"] ].sum(axis=1)`. This will only work for numeric columns though.